# Google api geocoding only get some values

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the [google geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). Everything is working fine. However when I search for 1 location I receive way to many information. I only need for example the `administrative_area_level_1`.

Url that I use:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.1224221,-68.8824233&sensor=false&key=mykey:)
```

I receive this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Kaya Toni Kunchi",
                    "short_name": "Kaya Toni Kunchi",
                    "types": [
                        "route"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Willemstad",
                    "short_name": "Willemstad",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Curaçao",
                    "short_name": "Curaçao",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Curaçao",
                    "short_name": "CW",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "Kaya Toni Kunchi, Willemstad, Curaçao",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.1237013,
                        "lng": -68.88351919999999
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 12.1234992,
                        "lng": -68.8842526
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 12.123662,
                    "lng": -68.88392089999999
                },
                "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.1249492302915,
                        "lng": -68.88253691970849
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 12.1222512697085,
                        "lng": -68.88523488029149
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJNcHwFUB9g44RuzTE4FqQ3UE",
            "types": [
                "route"
            ]
        },
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Santa Rosa",
                    "short_name": "Santa Rosa",
                    "types": [
                        "political",
                        "sublocality",
                        "sublocality_level_1"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Willemstad",
                    "short_name": "Willemstad",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Santa Maria",
                    "short_name": "Santa Maria",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Curaçao",
                    "short_name": "Curaçao",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Curaçao",
                    "short_name": "CW",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "Santa Rosa, Willemstad, Curaçao",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.1251383,
                        "lng": -68.8636779
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 12.1082708,
                        "lng": -68.8835479
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 12.1136041,
                    "lng": -68.87348109999999
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.1251383,
                        "lng": -68.8636779
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 12.1082708,
                        "lng": -68.8835479
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJLbPjNBJ9g44R9mOepLEBeF4",
            "types": [
                "political",
                "sublocality",
                "sublocality_level_1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Willemstad",
                    "short_name": "Willemstad",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Santa Maria",
                    "short_name": "Santa Maria",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Curaçao",
                    "short_name": "Curaçao",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Curaçao",
                    "short_name": "CW",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "Willemstad, Curaçao",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.1857187,
                        "lng": -68.8053561
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 12.0711749,
                        "lng": -68.9916729
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 12.1224221,
                    "lng": -68.8824233
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.1857187,
                        "lng": -68.8053561
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 12.0711749,
                        "lng": -68.9916729
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJVy-mDF-ChI4R701VMbSSSR8",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Curaçao",
                    "short_name": "Curaçao",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Curaçao",
                    "short_name": "CW",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "Curaçao",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.4151186,
                        "lng": -68.6109924
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 11.9627538,
                        "lng": -69.18834029999999
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 12.0989103,
                    "lng": -68.8585774
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.4151186,
                        "lng": -68.6109924
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 11.9627538,
                        "lng": -69.18834029999999
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJtWah-X1ig44RMbWx9gCSTJg",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Curaçao",
                    "short_name": "CW",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "Curaçao",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.4941999,
                        "lng": -68.5670001
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 11.9224,
                        "lng": -69.29899999999999
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 12.16957,
                    "lng": -68.99002
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 12.4941999,
                        "lng": -68.5670001
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 11.9224,
                        "lng": -69.29899999999999
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJx_3HYr6dhI4RI0fG2yiSf_w",
            "types": [
                "country",
                "political"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Right now I have to do this:

```
json_decode($response->getBody())->results[0]->address_components[4]->long_name;
```

And I get the `administrative_area_level_1`.

Is there a better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) in Geocoding API also allows to specify a type of results that you want to get. In order to get only result of type administrative_area_level_1 add a `result_type` parameter in your request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.1224221%2C-68.8824233&result_type=administrative_area_level_1&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The response will contain only administrative area level 1 item, so you can retrieve a name of administrative area as

`json_decode($response->getBody())->results[0]->formatted_address`

or

`json_decode($response->getBody())->results[0]->address_components[0]->long_name`

I hope this helps!